# ImgBurn fails to burn data CD-R disk due to "Layouts do not match" error

Tags: windows-7, compact-disc, imgburn

I have a reoccurring problem with the program ImgBurn. Whenever I try and burn anything to a CD-R using ImgBurn it burns just fine, except for when I go and verify the disk. It tells me that the "Layouts do not match". Windows 7 shows the disk as completely blank. Although, I see on the bottom of the disk it has been written to.

I can burn ISO files to DVD-R's just fine. This only seems to happen with CD-R's. The CD-R's I'm using are Memorex Cool Colors 52x CD-R's.

I have looked on Google, and it seems like I'm not the only one this happens to. Unfortunately, no one is able to provide an explanation.

I have included the log file from the last CD I just burnt. If you need anything else to better diagnose this problem, I will gladly provide it.

```
; //****************************************\\
;   ImgBurn Version 2.5.7.0 - Log
;   Monday, 19 November 2012, 16:11:57
; \\****************************************//
;
;
I 16:04:55 ImgBurn Version 2.5.7.0 started!
I 16:04:55 Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate x64 Edition (6.1, Build 7601 : Service Pack 1)
I 16:04:55 Total Physical Memory: 4,156,380 KB  -  Available: 3,317,144 KB
I 16:04:55 Initialising SPTI...
I 16:04:55 Searching for SCSI / ATAPI devices...
I 16:04:56 -> Drive 1 - Info: Optiarc DVD RW AD-7560S SH03 (D:) (SATA)
I 16:04:56 Found 1 DVD±RW/RAM!
I 16:05:37 Operation Started!
I 16:05:37 Source File: C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\VMware Workstation 9.iso
I 16:05:37 Source File Sectors: 223,057 (MODE1/2048)
I 16:05:37 Source File Size: 456,820,736 bytes
I 16:05:37 Source File Volume Identifier: VMwareWorksta9
I 16:05:37 Source File Volume Set Identifier: 20121119_2102
I 16:05:37 Source File File System(s): ISO9660, Joliet
I 16:05:37 Destination Device: [1:0:0] Optiarc DVD RW AD-7560S SH03 (D:) (SATA)
I 16:05:37 Destination Media Type: CD-R (Disc ID: 97m17s06f, Moser Baer India)
I 16:05:37 Destination Media Supported Write Speeds: 10x, 16x, 20x, 24x
I 16:05:37 Destination Media Sectors: 359,847
I 16:05:37 Write Mode: CD
I 16:05:37 Write Type: SAO
I 16:05:37 Write Speed: 6x
I 16:05:37 Lock Volume: Yes
I 16:05:37 Test Mode: No
I 16:05:37 OPC: No
I 16:05:37 BURN-Proof: Enabled
W 16:05:37 Write Speed Miscompare! - MODE SENSE: 1,764 KB/s (10x), GET PERFORMANCE: 11,080 KB/s (63x)
W 16:05:37 Write Speed Miscompare! - MODE SENSE: 1,764 KB/s (10x), GET PERFORMANCE: 11,080 KB/s (63x)
W 16:05:37 Write Speed Miscompare! - MODE SENSE: 1,764 KB/s (10x), GET PERFORMANCE: 11,080 KB/s (63x)
W 16:05:37 Write Speed Miscompare! - MODE SENSE: 1,764 KB/s (10x), GET PERFORMANCE: 11,080 KB/s (63x)
W 16:05:37 Write Speed Miscompare! - MODE SENSE: 1,764 KB/s (10x), GET PERFORMANCE: 11,080 KB/s (63x)
W 16:05:37 Write Speed Miscompare! - Wanted: 1,058 KB/s (6x), Got: 1,764 KB/s (10x) / 11,080 KB/s (63x)
W 16:05:37 The drive only supports writing these discs at 10x, 16x, 20x, 24x.
I 16:05:38 Filling Buffer... (80 MB)
I 16:05:40 Writing LeadIn...
I 16:06:07 Writing Session 1 of 1... (1 Track, LBA: 0 - 223056)
I 16:06:07 Writing Track 1 of 1... (MODE1/2048, LBA: 0 - 223056)
I 16:11:00 Synchronising Cache...
I 16:11:18 Exporting Graph Data...
I 16:11:18 Graph Data File: C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Roaming\ImgBurn\Graph Data Files\Optiarc_DVD_RW_AD-7560S_SH03_MONDAY-NOVEMBER-19-2012_4-05_PM_97m17s06f_6x.ibg
I 16:11:18 Export Successfully Completed!
I 16:11:18 Operation Successfully Completed! - Duration: 00:05:41
I 16:11:18 Average Write Rate: 1,522 KB/s (10.1x) - Maximum Write Rate: 1,544 KB/s (10.3x)
I 16:11:18 Cycling Tray before Verify...
W 16:11:23 Waiting for device to become ready...
I 16:11:47 Device Ready!
E 16:11:47 CompareImageFileLayouts Failed! - Session Count Not Equal (1/0)
E 16:11:47 Verify Failed! - Reason: Layouts do not match.
I 16:11:57 Close Request Acknowledged
I 16:11:57 Closing Down...
I 16:11:57 Shutting down SPTI...
I 16:11:57 ImgBurn closed!
```

Comment: Did you try asking the developer in the app's forum? I also suggest you try another batch for CD-Rs and burn at the slowest *supported* speed.

Comment: I didn't ask there, yet. Although it seems like I am going to have to. I was thinking the same about the CD's. I will obtain another brand and try again at the slowest supported speed which is 6x for me.

Comment: Slowest supported speed might be 6x for *you*, but ***Destination Media Supported Write Speeds*: 10x, 16x, 20x, 24x** is what actually matters.

Comment: @Karan I tried at the slowest speed I could and also the fastest. So, I don't think the burn speed can be the problem.

Comment: So just manually set it to 24×. Click the icon next to the drop-down (with the little green man running), and set it so that it always uses 24× for that drive with that media. As for the resulting disc, have you tried doing a manual comparison to the source like with WinMerge? If all of the files are identical, then there isn’t too much to worry about since it is a home-burned disc, not a factory-pressed disc which requires non-file bits to be exact (such as for copy-protection).

Answer (score 2):

Can you mount this ISO image with daemon tools or something?
Also, notice that from some reason he tries to write at 6x speed, which is not recognized by your hardware.
Try setting it to AWS:
[image]

Comment: I don't have Daemon tools, but I know that the ISO file is completely intact and isn't corrupted or anything. I used the AWS setting and the problem still persists. [Here is the log file from when I used the AWS setting](http://pastebin.com/fLS9vccJ)

Comment: So just manually set it to 24×. Click the icon next to the drop-down (with the little green man running), and set it so that it always uses 24× for that drive with that media.